# Method Not Allowed (POST): /login/

Tags: django, forms, post

I'm trying to get the users data using a form which I have in a `.html` file called `login.html`. The code for that is:

```
<form class="register-form" method="POST" action="{% url 'login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Username: </td>
        <td><input type="username" name="username"><br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password: </td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password"><br></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

I've already got a database with a bunch of users where username and passwords are stored. I want to create my own login page that checks against that database. What I'm trying to do is essentially get the user to the `login.html` page and then let the user enter the details and check against the database.

My `urls.py` looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^register$', include('register.urls')),
    url(r'^login/', include('login.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('home.urls')),
]
```

effectively it goes to the `login.urls` where the `urls.py` for that is:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from login import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.LoginPageView.as_view(), name='login'),
]
```

my `views.py` is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from person.models import Person

class LoginPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "login.html"
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):     
        print(request)
        return render(request, 'login.html')
```

**Problem** is that when I click the submit button, I want to check against the database, if unsuccessful, show error on the login page, otherwise, successfully authenticate the user and take them to the homepage.

Instead of it working I'm getting: 
`Method Not Allowed (POST): /login/
[21/Apr/2017 14:31:12] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0`

Thanks.

Comment: You are sending data in POST request and in View.py you are using class based views and in that class you are using get method instead of post method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sending data in POST request and in View.py you are using class based views and in that class you are using get method instead of post method.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from person.models import Person

class LoginPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "login.html"
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):     
        print(request)
        return render(request, 'login.html')
```

just replace your get method with post.